# Cleaning "SUM" Query

Tags: sql, syntax, sum, code-cleanup

I have a bit of sql code that look similar to this:

```
select sum(case when latitude = '0' then 1 else 0 end) as count_zero,
       sum(case when latitude is NULL then 1 else 0 end) as count_null,
       sum((case when latitude = '0' then 1 else 0 end) + 
           (case when latitude is NULL then 1 else 0 end)
          ) as total_zero, 
       count(latitude) as count_not_nulls,
       count(*) as total
from sites_database
```

Is there a "cleaner" way to write this same query. I have tried using the "sum" expression using the column alias, something like:

```
Sum(count_zero + count_null) as total_null
```

But this doesn't seem to work for some reason

Comment: Indenting it improves it, but the query is fine.

Comment: When the type of `latitude` is a numeric type (which seems right) then you don't need the single quotes around the literals. I.e. instead of `'0'` just `0` is better.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `COUNT` instead of `SUM`:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN latitude = '0' THEN 1 END) As count_zero,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN latitude IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS count_null,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN COALESCE(latitude, '0') = '0' THEN 1 END) AS total_zero, 
    COUNT(latitude) As count_not_nulls,
    COUNT(*) as total
FROM sites_database;
```

Using `COUNT` here saves a bit of coding, because we don't have to provide an explicit `ELSE` condition (the default `ELSE` is `NULL`, which just isn't counted at all).  Also note that for the `total_zero` conditional sum, I used `COALESCE` to merge the two counts into just one.